# Merging data frames with repeated row names

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have the 2 data frames 'data1' and 'data2'.

```
data1 <- data.frame(gene=c("ABCD11","ABCD2","ABCD2"),value1=c(2,5,9))

> data1
    gene value1
1 ABCD11      2
2  ABCD2      5
3  ABCD2      9

data2 <- data.frame(gene=c("ABCD11","ABCD2","ABCD2"),value2=c(32,35,39))

> data2
    gene value2
1 ABCD11     32
2  ABCD2     35
3  ABCD2     39
```

I want to merge them into one data frame, 'data_merge', where the output would be something like this:

```
data_merge <- data.frame(gene=c("ABCD11","ABCD2","ABCD2"),value1=c(2,5,9),value2=c(32,35,39))

> data_merge
    gene value1 value2
1 ABCD11      2     32
2  ABCD2      5     35
3  ABCD2      9     39
```

I have tried `merge()`, `left_join()`, `full_join()`. All of them provide the output:

```
    gene value1 value2
1 ABCD11      2     32
2  ABCD2      5     35
3  ABCD2      5     39
4  ABCD2      9     35
5  ABCD2      9     39
```

Comment: You could try `cbind(data1, data2$value2)`. The problem you are having with the join functions is that the gene variable  elements are not unique, hence the duplication of values. The `cbind` option is only reliable if the order of the  gene variable is identical in both data frames.

Comment: You only need to use a merge/join function if the rows are in different orders in the different data frames. In your case, the rows are in the same order so you can copy a column directly, `data1$value2 = data2$value2`.

Comment: If your rows are in different orders and you do need to match `gene` values, then `merge`/`join` functions are appropriate. If, further, you care that the *first* occurrence of a gene value in `data1` is matched to only the *first* occurrence of a gene value in `data2`, then you'll need to add another column that numbers the occurrences. With `library(dplyr)` you could do `data1 = mutate(data1, occ = row_number(), .by = gene)`, do the same for `data2`, then `left_join(data1, data2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can `bind_cols`, subsetting the dataframe to be added by the `set difference` in names. A fragile operation, because it relies on the asumption of equally sorted `gene` columns across data.frames.

```
library(dplyr)

data1 |> 
    bind_cols(select(data2, all_of(setdiff(names(data2), names(data1)))))

    gene value1 value2
1 ABCD11      2     32
2  ABCD2      5     35
3  ABCD2      9     39
```

Comment: Any suggestions in case I am reading in, say 10 data.frames and I am not sure about the ordering of the row.

Answer (score 1):

```
column_to_rownames(full_join(rownames_to_column(data1), rownames_to_column(data2)))

    gene value1 value2
1 ABCD11      2     32
2  ABCD2      5     35
3  ABCD2      9     39
```